# Efficiently find deep marked children of tree node

Tags: performance, algorithm, tree, computer-science, children

Given a (m-way) tree T:

```
        A
       / \
      B   C
     / \   \
    D*  E*  F
   / \   \   \
  G   H*  I   J*
```

With the marked nodes D*, E* H* and J*, is there a fast way to retrieve *all* marked children under a given node, apart from walking all subtrees or storing all marked children for every node? I.e:

```
B -> D*, E*, H*
C -> J*
A -> D*, E*, H*, J*
```

Comment: There are plenty of different ways to store intermediate results for speeding this up, but without more context, it's hard to tell what would be helpful.

Comment: @PhilBolduc please ensure you think before you post - thank you.

Comment: @trutheality I need this for some UI work; basically, subwidgets must be able to receive resize events whenever *any* of their parents' size changes - i.e. if a window is resized some deeply buried textbox must receive a resize event, but no widgets in-between.

Comment: If you need this for handling nested UIs it strikes me as a case where optimizing it is not really necessary. How deeply nested can you tree actually be, 100, 200, 300 layers ? Just walking the tree is going to be fast enough even if you have 1000 layers (which is probably a ridiculous number of nestings anyway)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you have a tradeoff between walking the tree and storing lists of your marked values. You mentioned the two extremes, I will give you an example below that sits somewhere in the middle between them.

One idea that comes to mind is storing the next "layer" of marked children at each marked node, that should give a pretty balanced mix between storage and time, so in your example it wouldn't save much, but for example if you have

```
        A
       / \
      B*  C
     / \   \
    D*  E   F
   / \   \   \
  G   H*  I*  J*
 /   / \
K   L   M
```

You would store `D,I` in `B` and `H` in `D` and "empty" markers in `H,I,J`.

To get the list for a node you only have to walk until every branch hits a marked node, so for example, to get the list for `A`, you would have to walk from `A->B` and `A->C->F->J`, then `B` would give you `I,D`, `D` would give you `H`.

You can also think of it as storing trees of marked nodes only alongside with the original tree, in this case, the two trees

```
  B        J
 / \
D   I
|
H
```

Depending on the distribution of marked nodes, you might be able to optimize this idea for your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you go bottom up you can visit much smaller portions of the tree.

This algorithm can work **the tree** expressed in minimal space: i.e. just a vector of structs, full payload except a 'parent node' index and a 'marked flag' (-1 for the root).

```
for each node
  if marked && given parent in parents'chain
    ok, save (for instance) the index
  endif
next
```

IMO, and depending on the data distribution statistic, I feel this could be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can store one bit (or `boolean`) in every node which is 1 (`true`) if and only if there is a marked node in the subtree rooted in the current node. This labeling is easy to maintain while updating the tree and allows you to skip uninteresting subtrees easily in both recursive and iterative algorithms. You have to traverse all nodes on paths to marked nodes, though.

Another idea that ensures zero overhead for accesses but is harder to maintain is this: let every marked node have a second pair of child pointers. With these, you can store the tree of marked nodes with little storage overhead. You can even encode the marking itself this way; a node is marked if and only if at least one of those pointers is not `null`. The root has to be treated in a special way.

Comment: I like the flag idea, but the problem is that you'd still have to traverse a lot of intermediate unmarked nodes. But your second suggestion (and if I understood correctly this is basically the same idea as trutheality's) actually makes the flags unnecessary and is what I'm gonna do :)

Comment: @PhilipK Wether the first one introduces too much overhead really depends on your situation, i.e. how many labels you have relatively. I did not fully understand what trutheality was up to.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to walk the tree at least once. There's no faster way than that. You don't want to store them so you'll have to walk them anew every time.

Comment: Well I would be ok with storing them, I just don't want to store a list of all marked subnodes in every subnode (and it would have to be *every* node). If there's an efficient way of storing them - I'm all for it.